In 3D plotting, how get traditional position and orientation of xyz-axes
The traditional way in math when doing 3D plotting is to use a "positively oriented" set of axes, and with:

the z-axis points vertically upward;
the x-axis points, as it were, leftward and forward out of the picture;
the y-axis points rightward and forward;
if you wrap your right hand around the z-axis, then your fingers curl in a directions fron the x-axis to the y-axis (in other words, if you look down the z-axis toward the xy-plane, then moving around the origin from the x-axis to the y-axis goes counterclockwise).

But this is not how Mathematica displays its set of axes.
As the plot below shows, Mathematica does use a positively oriented set of axes (just look at where the arrowheads are on the axes) despite labeling with "y" the *negative" y-axis.
By contast,
what the traditional format would be is to have the positive x-axis where the negative y-axis is in the plot, and the positive y-axis where the positive x-axis is in the plot.
QUESTION How does one get the axes to be positively oriented and in the traditional locations?
Please don't just tell me to use Viewpoint but if that is the tool — and I'm not convinced it will be — please show me exactly how.
With[{r = 0.6, R = 2.85},
 X[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (R + r Cos[\[Phi]]) Cos[\[Theta]];
 Y[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (R + r Cos[\[Phi]]) Sin[\[Theta]];
 Z[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := r Sin[\[Phi]];
 origin = {0, 0, 0};
 labelStyle[lbl_] := 
  Style[lbl, Italic, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 18];
 Show[{
   ParametricPlot3D[{X[\[Theta], \[Phi]], Y[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
     Z[\[Theta], \[Phi]]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/4}, {\[Phi], 0, 
     2 \[Pi]},
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-3, 3}},
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> origin, AxesStyle -> Thick, Ticks -> None, 
    AxesLabel -> labelStyle /@ {"x", "y", "z"}],
   Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.0325], Arrow[{origin, {4.25, 0, 0}}], 
     Arrowheads[0.035], Arrow[{origin, {0, 4.25, 0}}], 
     Arrowheads[0.0325], Arrow[{origin, {0, 0, 3}}]}, Boxed -> False]
   }]
 ]


Related: Change Plot3D, etc., axes orientation and position?

What's wrong with ViewPoint? That would seem the most convenient strategy to me.

You are wrong, both set of axes are "right handed". What you call "traditional format" is simply a rotation of the axes around the z-axis by Pi/4. You can achieve this by setting the ViewPoint e.g. like:
With[{r = 0.6, R = 2.85}, 
 X[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (R + r Cos[\[Phi]]) Cos[\[Theta]];
 Y[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (R + r Cos[\[Phi]]) Sin[\[Theta]];
 Z[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := r Sin[\[Phi]];
 origin = {0, 0, 0};
 labelStyle[lbl_] := 
  Style[lbl, Italic, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times", 18];
 Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{X[\[Theta], \[Phi]], Y[\[Theta], \[Phi]], 
     Z[\[Theta], \[Phi]]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/4}, {\[Phi], 0, 
     2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-3, 3}}, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> origin, 
    AxesStyle -> Thick, Ticks -> None, 
    AxesLabel -> labelStyle /@ {"x", "y", "z"}], 
   Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.0325], Arrow[{origin, {4.25, 0, 0}}], 
     Arrowheads[0.035], Arrow[{origin, {0, 4.25, 0}}], 
     Arrowheads[0.0325], Arrow[{origin, {0, 0, 3}}]}, 
    Boxed -> False]}, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]]



Yes, I realized my mistake and corrected it before just seeing your answer.
